# Rails - Facebook Connect, where to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I have a small web app, and I would like to allow for facebook connect to get the users photo. So where should I start to do integration with facebook and my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rails & facebook integration there is this nice ruby gem called Facebooker(http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/). There is also a pragmatic programmers book titled Developing Facebook platform application using ruby on rails (http://www.pragprog.com/titles/mmfacer/developing-facebook-platform-applications-with-rails). I haven't personally used facebooker though there is a nice tutorial with facebook connect and rails here -> http://blog.moove-it.com/using-facebooker-to-make-a-rails-site-with-facebook-connect-part-1/.

Comment: Facebooker is for the old REST API; [Facebooker2](https://rubygems.org/gems/facebooker2) is for the new graph API but I'm not sure how stable it is.

Answer (score 18):

I strongly recommend checking out [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth), it makes the process of integrating with Facebook and many other third-party authentication providers orders of magnitudes easier. The readme and wiki on GitHub are pretty good, and Ryan Bates has done [several screencasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=omniauth) on the subject.

[fb_graph](https://rubygems.org/gems/fb_graph) is another popular Facebook-only gem, as is [Koala](https://rubygems.org/gems/koala).